# Include a fragment from the same thymeleaf template using "this :: content" or ":: content" not working as expected

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I'm including a template fragment from the same template file. Section "[8.1 Including template fragments - Defining and referencing fragments](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#including-template-fragments)" of the docs states that:

> "**::domselector**" or "**this::domselector**" Includes a fragment from the
>   same template.

If I haven't misunderstood, I should be able to reference the fragment as follows: `th:include="this :: contentB"` or `th:include=":: contentB"`
but only making full reference `th:include="test-fragment :: contentB"` works for me.

This is the sample code:

*HomeController.java*

```
@Controller
class HomeController {
  @RequestMapping({ "/", "index", "home" })
  String index(Model model) {
    return "test";
  }
}
```

*test.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <ul th:replace="test-fragment :: contentA" />
  </body>
</html>
```

*test-fragment.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <ul th:fragment="contentA">
      <li th:each="idx : ${#numbers.sequence(1,4)}" th:switch="${idx}">

        <th:block th:case="1" 
            th:include="test-fragment :: contentB" 
            th:with="strVar = 'One'"/>

        <th:block th:case="2" 
            th:include="this :: contentB"
            th:with="strVar = 'Two'"/>

        <th:block th:case="3" 
            th:include=" :: contentB"
            th:with="strVar = 'Three'"/>

        <th:block th:case="*" 
            th:include="/test-fragment :: contentB" 
            th:with="strVar = 'Other'"/>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <span th:fragment="contentB">
      <span th:text="|value: ${strVar}|" />
    </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Output is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <ul>
         <li><span>value: One</span></li>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
         <li><span>value: Other</span></li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

Case 2 and 3 are missing. What am I doing wrong?

I'm testing using [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) 1.3.2.RELEASE

EDIT:

I've made a small test project to reproduce the issue, it can be found here: https://github.com/t-cst/thymeleaf-springboot-test

EDIT:

After some debug, I find out that when the fragment selector is `"this :: contentB"` or  `" :: contentB"` then the template name is resolved as `test`  instead of `test-framgent`. This is done at:

`StandardFragment#extractFragment:189` from thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE:

```
/* 186 */  String targetTemplateName = getTemplateName();
           if (targetTemplateName == null) {
               if (context != null && context instanceof Arguments) {
                   targetTemplateName = ((Arguments)context).getTemplateName();
/* 190 */      } else {
                   throw new TemplateProcessingException(
                           "In order to extract fragment from current template (templateName == null), processing context " +
                           "must be a non-null instance of the Arguments class (but is: " +
                           (context == null? null : context.getClass().getName()) + ")");
/* 195 */      }
           }
```

But I still don't know why this happens in my test.

EDIT:

I've also asked  at [thymeleaf forum](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Include-a-fragment-from-the-same-thymeleaf-template-using-quot-this-content-quot-or-quot-content-quod-td4029523.html). Maybe it's a bug. I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/466).

Comment: I tried it on a normal Spring MVC running in a regular tomcat 7 container. Your code is working fine. I couldn't reproduce your issue... weird

Comment: yes, really weird. I've also tried deploying as a war in tomcat-7.0.57 and tomcat-8.0.32 with same result. I guess it's something related with thymeleaf-spring4 and the ViewResolver.

Comment: My thymeleaf and thymeleaef-spring4 version are 2.1.4.RELEASE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone ends here with the same issue, this is not possible in `thymeleaf 2.1.4.RELEASE` version, but it will be in next version `3.0`

A comprehensive explanation can be found at this [issue comment](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/466#issuecomment-188984196).